# El código funciona bien o a medias independientemente de si lo cambio o no

Tags: c++, eclipse, dev-c++

Este es mi código, es un "mapa" de un garaje que simplemente tiene que rellenar los huecos con los números de las plazas y si está cogida en vez del numero pone una x. El mapa está compuesto por un array de strings. Lo que hago para rellenar los espacios es crear dos strings nuevos, uno con todo lo previo al hueco y otro con lo posterior, y al final lo construyo mediante sumas dentro de un tercer nuevo string, result.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool checkReserva(int plaza) {
    bool esCierto = false;
    /*int tamanyoReserva = cuentaReservas(db);
     Reserva *reservas = new Reserva[tamanyoReserva];
     recogeReservas(reservas, db);*/
    int tamanyoReserva = 5;
    int reservas[] = { 20, 22, 12, 3, 12 };
    int var;
    for (var = 0; var < tamanyoReserva; ++var) {
        if (reservas[var] == plaza) {
            esCierto = true;
            return esCierto;
        }
    }
    return esCierto;
}

int main() {
    string *map = new string[10];

    map[0] = "  ===================";
    map[1] = "// [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] \\\\";
    map[2] = "||                    ||";
    map[3] = "|| [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] ||";
    map[4] = "|| [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] ||";
    map[5] = "||                    ||";
    map[6] = "|| [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] ||";
    map[7] = "|| [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] ||";
    map[8] = "||                    ||";
    map[9] = "\\\\ [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] //";
    map[10] = "  ===================";
    int piso = 1;
    int plaza = 0;

    int numPlaza[36];

    int y;
    for (y = 0; y < 36; ++y) {
        numPlaza[y] = plaza;
        plaza++;
    }
    string prev;
    string post;
    string num;
    string result;
    int iteradorNumPlaza = 0;
    unsigned int var;
    for (var = 0; var < 11; ++var) {
        result.clear();
        if (var == 0 || var == 2 || var == 5 || var == 8 || var == 10) {

            result = map[var];
        } else {
            unsigned int x;
            for (x = 0; x != map[var].length(); ++x) {
                if (map[var][x] == '[' && map[var][x + 2] == ']') {
                    if (checkReserva(numPlaza[iteradorNumPlaza]) == true) {
                        prev = map[var].substr(0, x + 1);
                        post = map[var].substr(x + 2);

                        map[var] = prev + "x" + post;
                        result = prev + "x" + post;
                    } else {
                        prev = map[var].substr(0, x + 1);
                        post = map[var].substr(x + 2);
                        num = to_string(numPlaza[iteradorNumPlaza]);

                        map[var] = prev + num + post;
                        result = prev + num + post;
                    }
                    iteradorNumPlaza++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << map[var] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sin hacer ningún cambio cuando ejecuto el código, a veces el resultado es a) o b), a que se puede deber esto?

a)

```
 ===================
// [0][1][2][x][4][5] \\
||                    ||
|| [6][7][8][9][10][11] ||
|| [x][13][14][15][16][17] ||
||                    ||
|| [18][19][x][21][x][23] ||
|| [24][25][26][27][28][29] ||
||                    ||
\\ [30][31][32][33][34][35] //
  ===================
```

b)

```
 ===================
// [0][1][2][x][4][5] \\
||                    ||
|| [6][7][8][9][10][11] ||
|| [x][13][14][15][16][17] ||
||                    ||
```

Comment: Si te salen resultados direfentes cada vez sin cambiar el codigo probablemente
estes haciendo algo que involucre comportamiendo indefinido. Viendolo con un
address sanitizer [resulta ser que si](https://godbolt.org/z/frve9dnqY). Puedes
ver el comentario que te dejo para ver el error del que habla. Problemente estes
cayendo en varios de estos errores. No uses `new`, usa `std::unique_ptr` (O para
lo que tu quieres es mucho mejor `std::vector`). Y si
usas `new` minimo llama a `delete` despues.

Comment: Hola maikel, me puedes decir si la respuesta te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes trabajar con matrices.

Una matriz es una estructura conformada por filas y columnas, las matrices pueden tener n-dimensiones, pero la más común es la matriz bidimensional, es decir en forma de tabla como la de tu ejemplo, en cambio un arreglo unidimensional se le conoce como vector.

Para acceder a un elemento específico de una matriz tenemos que hacerlo de esta forma:

```
valor = matriz[i][j];
```

donde i y j son los índices donde se encuentra ese elemento en la matriz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo que pones tienes una matriz con dimensiones 6x6, es decir 6 filas y 6 columnas, por tanto:

```
char mapa[6][6];
int reservas[] = { 20, 22, 12, 3, 12 };
int pos = 0;
bool reservado = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < 6 ; j++)
   {
      for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
      {
         if(reservas[k] == pos)
         {
            reservado = true;
            break;
         }

         if(reservado)
         {
            mapa[i][j] = 'x';
         }             
      }

      reservado = false;
      pos++;
   }
}
```

Lo que se hace en este código es declarar una matriz de 6x6 que nos servirá de mapa, tenemos ademas un arreglo con las reservas.

Posteriormente vamos a recorrer la matriz con dos **ciclos for** anidados, y un tercer **ciclo for** que nos servirá para verificar si alguna reserva está en la posición actual donde nos encontramos en la matriz, es ahí donde entra en juego la **variable entera pos**, ya que en esta variable guardamos la posición en donde nos encontramos, simulando que en vez de una matriz recorremos un arreglo.

Preguntamos si alguno de los elementos del **arreglo reserva** coincide con nuestra posición actual y de ser cierto, le damos valor **true** a la **variable reservado** y salimos de ese ciclo mediante un **break**.

Si la **variable reservado** toma el valor de **true** quiere decir que esa posición está ocupada, por tanto marcamos esa posición de la matriz con una **'x'**. Posteriormente le damos el valor **false** a la **variable reservado** y aumentamos la posición, y se vuelven a repetir los ciclos una y otra vez repitiendo todo el proceso hasta que finalicen.

Revisa este código y adáptalo al tuyo.

Comment: @Pablochaches, arreglado, gracias